# Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, conf.int, value = list(X1 = c(-0.305562185432494, : replacement has 2 rows, data has 20

Tags: r

I would like to add the output of t.test function conf.int in data frames, using below code

```
y <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1000),20))
test <- apply(y, 1, t.test, alternative = c("two.sided", "less", "greater"),mu = 0, paired = FALSE, var.equal = FALSE,conf.level = 0.95)
y$conf.int <-data.frame(sapply(test,function(x)c(x$conf.int)))
```

However it return

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, w, value = list(X1 = c(-0.305562185432494,  : replacement has 2 rows, data has 20
```

I searched for solution and then modified the code as given below

```
y$x1_range <- NA
y$x1_range[which(y$x1 <= 2)] <-data.frame(sapply(test,function(x)c(x$conf.int)))
```

But it creating only empty column, nothing else.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to `t`ranspose the output

```
y[c('conf.int1', 'conf.int2')] <- data.frame(t(sapply(test,function(x)c(x$conf.int))))
```

-output

```
> head(y, 2)
          X1          X2         X3        X4        X5        X6        X7         X8          X9       X10       X11       X12      X13       X14
1 -0.9634687 -1.14768833 -0.4581778  1.354737 -2.646997 -1.116527 1.3625804 -0.5687561  0.79465750 -2.430073  1.135271  1.053663 1.382226 0.5173209
2  1.1248102 -0.06809104 -0.6283953 -1.550826 -1.512092 -1.002261 0.2195859  0.2703556 -0.09471368 -1.710448 -1.216440 -2.768706 0.566922 0.4230643
         X15       X16          X17       X18       X19       X20        X21      X22        X23        X24        X25       X26        X27
1 1.28908680 0.4187469  0.003371298  1.465830 -1.260173  1.173877 -0.7095292 2.229795  0.5523339 -0.8087554 -0.1561967 -1.306025 0.53076476
2 0.07278306 0.2980650 -1.551135977 -1.973276 -1.426402 -2.486149 -0.7273097 2.858042 -1.1409915  1.0112357  0.3947225  1.556861 0.04759532
        X28      X29        X30       X31       X32       X33       X34        X35        X36        X37        X38        X39        X40
1  1.529848 1.084488 -0.3461915 0.7718974 -0.169598 0.9749795 -1.553482 -0.2820139  0.6066046 -0.6228313 -0.3230779  1.3889745 -1.9377144
2 -1.450150 1.711763  1.0571177 0.2451662 -1.907372 2.4889987 -1.698743  0.3402877 -0.4900094 -0.1871107 -0.1044987 -0.8285744  0.7367646
          X41        X42        X43        X44        X45        X46        X47         X48        X49        X50  conf.int1 conf.int2
1  1.17811571 0.04814796 -1.1974972 -0.6465730  0.5980972 -0.6551301 -0.9230456  0.06713694 -0.6634514 -0.3395491 -0.3112957 0.3224969
2 -0.09476432 0.20639926 -0.2591858 -0.7328225 -0.2777821  0.8491342  0.1102968 -1.04740247  0.4924049  0.1384269 -0.571338
```

Comment: Thank you, dear. It is working and now I also learned how to transpose and when need to apply it.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract `'conf.int'` from `test` to get 2 column matrix and `cbind` to original `y`.

```
y <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1000),20))

test <- apply(y, 1, t.test, alternative = c("two.sided", "less", "greater"),
              mu = 0, paired = FALSE, var.equal = FALSE,conf.level = 0.95)

result <- cbind(y, t(sapply(test, `[[`, 'conf.int')))
```